# Closure of a set proof

Tags: real-analysis

[image]

[image]

I don't understand where the bit highlighted in green comes from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that all $y_n\in\bar{A}$ and according to the definition of $\bar A$ this means there exists a sequence $\{x_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ such that $x_i\to y_n$ as $i\to\infty$.

This means in particular that for every $y_n$ we can find an $x_n$ such that $|x_n-y_n|<\frac{1}{n}$ (because we can come arbitrarily close). By choosing this $x_n$ for every $y_n$ we obtain 
$$
|x_n-y_n|<\frac{1}{n}
$$
for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since the whole sequence $y_n$ is in the closure of $A$, then there must, by the definition of "closure", be a sequence of points in $A$ converging to each particular $y_n$, which means we can choose points in $A$ as close as we like to each $y_n$. The idea is to take a point $x_1$ within $1$ unit of $y_1$, then a point $x_2$ within 1/2 a unit of $y_2$, then a point $x_3$ within 1/3 unit of $y_3$, etc.

In this way, we generate a sequence $x_n$, which converges to the same point that the sequence $y_n$ converges to, namely $y$.